# Elasticsearch in open edx fullstack has an error

Tags: elasticsearch, openedx

I installed fullstack open edx on Ubuntu 12.04 and then I use my fork edx-platform repo. When it finished, elasticsearch cannot use for finding courses. It always show "We couldn't find any results for" message.

I check log on elasticsearch.log I met this error.

```
2015-09-17 10:20:33,241][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Graydon Creed] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x5255e28c, /192.168.33.1:54633 :> /192.168.33.10:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:482)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
```

This is cluster status.

```
vagrant@precise64:/etc/elasticsearch$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty=true'
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Jericho Drumm",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.11",
    "build_hash" : "11da1bacf39cec400fd97581668acb2c5450516c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-02-03T15:27:39Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.6"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
vagrant@precise64:/etc/elasticsearch$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 10,
  "active_shards" : 10,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 10
}
```

How I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when somebody misconfigures elasticsearch REST client by specifying port `9300` instead of port `9200`. Check configuration of the client running on `192.168.33.1` and make sure that it uses `9200`.